# Passing negative number literals to extension properties/methods in Swift

Tags: swift, operator-precedence, lexical-analysis

I wrote a few number extensions for unit conversions, for example:

```
public extension Double {
    public var dbamp: Double {
        return pow(10, self/20)
    }
}
public extension Int {
    public var dbamp: Double {
        return Double(self).dbamp
    }
}
```

For computing a linear gain multiplier from a db value.  The problem is, intuitively I'd expect (and want to be able to write) something like `-6.dbamp` to return the result for a value of `(-6).dbamp`, whereas instead the result is `-(6.dbamp)`.

The [swift documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/LexicalStructure.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH30-ID414) states that

> Negative integers literals are expressed by prepending a minus sign (-) to an integer literal, as in -42.

However, it seems that `-42` isn't really an integer literal, but an expression involving the `-` operator and the integer literal `42`. Perhaps this behaviour is not unique to Swift.

I suppose it may be possible to get the desired behaviour using custom precedence / associativity somehow, but I feel rather nervous doing anything that may be liable to cause potentially obscure bugs down the line for the sake of a dash of syntactic sugar.  If it would be necessary to alter precedence of `-` operator, that seems clearly not a price worth paying...

Comment: I don't understand this, if I run your code for 6 and -6 I get 1.995 and 0.501. Isn't this the expected result?

Comment: Nevermind, I did "*= -1" instead of just adding a - sign in front of my variable. The latter doesn't work for me either.

Comment: Yeah, it's not really such a big deal... but something to beware of, could potentially hide an obscure bug at some point.